# glTranslatef gets messed up after glRotatef

Tags: python, pyopengl, opengl-compat

I'm a newbie to PyOpenGL. I made a simple code using it that displays a cube, and you can navigate around it using the keyboard. However, I noticed that after a glRotatef command gets called, it changes your perspective, not the positionment of the objects. However, glTranslatef does not work on perspective, and rather a literal coordinate system. In other words, after calling a glRotatef command by 90*, a glTranslatef command that would have moved you forward now moves you to the left. Is there a function like glTranslatef, only it changes with the rotation so you don't get weird motions, or some sort of workaround you can do, to change the values you pass to glTranslatef based on the rotation?

Comment: The order of transformations is important in OpenGL. Did you try the other way around?

Comment: It may help you to maintain coordinates and rotations on your program in terms of "world space", and then perform the gl transformations every frame in order to get the "screen space" representation to be seen on screen.  Trying to backtrack as you're describing when graduating between these coordinate spaces will generally lead to trouble, and as mentioned the order of transformations does matter, so try to create a consistent one-way pipeline for this task so you can let world logic be world logic and GL logic be GL logic

Comment: I can't really do it the other way around. The transformations are based upon user input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Operations like [`glTranslate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTranslate.xml) and [`glRotate`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glRotate.xml) define a (translation respectively rotation) matrix and multiply the current matrix by the new matrix.
The [matrix multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication) is not [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). If you want to rotate the model an translate the model independent of the rotation, then you have to do the rotation before the translation respectively multiply the translation matrix by the rotation matrix:
(OpenGL matrix multiplications have to be read from the right to the left):

```
modelmatrix = translation * rotation
```

Respectively `glTranslate` before `glRotate`:

```py
glTranslate(x, y, z)
glRotate(angle, ax, ay, az)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, unfortunately it is not what I am looking for. The translations are based upon user input, so I cannot control them. Think of the question this way: if you're looking at the left of an object, and it moves forward, to you is seems like is has moved left. I'd like for it to seem like it is always moving forward, even from a different angle of perspective.

Comment: @user12692182 I see. What you want is a first person camera. But that is not what you've asked in your question.

Comment: It is not? If you know what exactly I am asking for,, could you edit my question?, or should I make a new question entirely

Comment: @user12692182 The title of the question (*"glTranslatef gets messed up after glRotatef"*) is misleading and does not describe the issue. Anyway I'll think about a better answer.

Comment: Okay, I'll make a new question